# Configuration Devise and omniauth in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook

I have a problem with both gems, because when I try to connect to my webpage with Facebook (Sign Up or Login) tell me they send a email confirmation or I need to confirm the email confirmation.

But the problem is that never send me a email, and other thing, if I don't want send a email when I Sign in my web across Facebook.

I put the code.

## app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
    class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

## app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}

  has_many :rooms
  has_many :reservations

  has_many :guest_reviews, class_name: "GuestReview", foreign_key: "guest_id"
  has_many :host_reviews, class_name: "HostReview", foreign_key: "host_id"

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = User.where(email: auth.info.email).first

    if user
      return user
    else
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.fullname = auth.info.name
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.provider = auth.provider

        # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate emails,
        # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
        user.skip_confirmation!
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: The way you have written this the user will never be updated if it already exists - so if you used the email of an exisisting user then `user.skip_confirmation!` is never called.

Comment: Have you configured the email in your environment initializer ?

Comment: I drop the database and creating again. It's working fine, but now don't permit me login with Facebook.